# scrollIntoView() Doesn't work with angular Material Mat-Menu-Item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with angular material and scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' }).

I trying to click in a mat-menu-item, that is inside an item in a mat-table, and scroll to an especific html tag

this is my target

```
<h1 #formUpdate class="titles">{{ editOrCreate$ | async }}</h1>
```

First Attempt

here is my html code that i need make work

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="formUpdate.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })">Top</button>
</mat-menu>
```

the code above, is not working, but if i try in a different way, like a button outside my table, it works
Code i've tried

```
<button mat-button (click)="formUpdate.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })">Top</button>
```

the code above works

Second Attempt

I've tried to make it in the file.ts, like can be seen in the code below

file.html

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="updateItem(formUpdate )">Top</button>
</mat-menu>
```

file.ts

```
export class WorkspacesComponent{

    public updateItem(formUpdate){
        target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
}
```

All code.html

```
<!-- INÍCIO - Parte de criar/editar/importar assunto(workspace) -->

<section class="at-container edit-create-table wrap-row display-flex mat-elevation-z2 new-wksp" #formUpdate>

    <form class="form" [formGroup]="(workspaceForm$ | async)" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="executeOperation(null, formDirective)">

        <!-- Title -->
        <h2 class="titles">{{ editOrCreate$ | async }}</h2>
        <!-- Title -->

        <!-- name Form field-->
        <mat-form-field class="form-field">
            <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Nome" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- name Form field-->

        <!-- Description Form field -->
        <div class="new-wksp-txtarea">
            <mat-form-field class="form-field">
                <textarea matInput formControlName="description" placeholder="Descrição" required></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <!-- Description Form field -->

        <!-- Language Form field -->
        <mat-form-field class="form-field">
            <mat-select formControlName="language" placeholder="Idioma" [(value)]="language" required>
                <mat-option value="pt-br">Português</mat-option>
                <!-- <mat-option value="en-us">English</mat-option> -->
                <!-- <mat-option value="es-la">Español</mat-option> -->
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- Language Form field -->

        <!-- Import Form -->
        <div class="new-wksp-file display-flex wrap-row">
            <form class="new-wksp-file-form display-flex wrap-row" #spreadsheet="ngForm" [attr.disabled]="(disabled$ | async)"
                enctype="multipart/form-data" id="spreadsheet" name="spreadsheet" (ngSubmit)="executeOperation(spreadsheet, null)"
                novalidate>
                <div class="new-wksp-file-form-toggle display-flex wrap-row">
                    <h3 class="new-wksp-file-form-toggle-title display-flex">Importar planilha ?</h3>
                    <span class="yes-not ml-2" [ngClass]=" !(import$ | async ) ? 'yes-not-active' : 'yes-not-inactive' ">Não</span>
                    <mat-slide-toggle class="toggle" [checked]="(import$ | async )" [disabled]="(disabled$ | async)"
                        (change)="setActive(!import$.value)"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    <span class="yes-not" [ngClass]=" (import$ | async ) ? 'yes-not-active' : 'yes-not-inactive' ">Sim</span>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(import$ | async )" class="new-wksp-file-form-select">
                    <div class="chose-file display-flex wrap-row">
                        <div class="import-divFile">
                            <span class="import-divFile-fileName">{{ !(csv$ | async) ? (fileName$ | async) : NAS }}</span>
                            <input #file type="file" class="" (change)="selectFile($event, false)" accept="application/json"
                                hidden>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" [disabled]="(disabled$ | async)" class="at-btn ot-btn" (click)="file.click()">Escolher
                            Arquivo</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="new-wksp-divButton display-flex">
                        <button class="at-btn at-btn-reset" type="reset" [disabled]="!(fileSelected$ | async)" (click)="setActive(false)">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="at-btn at-btn-submit ml-2" [disabled]="(!(fileSelected$ | async) || (disabled$ | async))">Importar
                            Planilha
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Download Template -->
                <div *ngIf="(import$ | async )" class="display-flex wrap-row download-template onImportForm">
                    <h2 class="download-template-title">Fazer download do Template de Assunto?</h2>
                    <input #template type="file" (change)="selectFile($event, true)" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                        hidden>
                    <button type="button" [disabled]="(disabled$ | async)" class="at-btn ot-btn" (click)="template.click()">Download
                        Template</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Download Template -->
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Import Form -->

        <!-- Download Template -->
        <div *ngIf="!(import$ | async )" class="display-flex wrap-row download-template">
            <h2 class="download-template-title">Fazer download do Template de Assunto?</h2>
            <input #template type="file" (change)="selectFile($event, true)" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                hidden>
            <button type="button" [disabled]="(disabled$ | async)" class="at-btn ot-btn" (click)="template.click()">Download
                Template</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Download Template -->

        <!-- POST/PUT Workspace button -->
        <div *ngIf="!(import$ | async )" class="new-wksp-divButton display-flex">
            <button class="at-btn at-btn-reset" type="reset" (click)="reset()" [disabled]="(!workspaceForm$.value.dirty && workspaceForm$.value.invalid)">Limpar</button>
            <button type="submit" *ngIf="!(import$ | async )" class="at-btn at-btn-submit ml-2" [ngClass]="workspaceForm$.getValue().invalid ? 'submit-button-inactive' : 'submit-button-active' "
                [disabled]="workspaceForm$.getValue().invalid">{{ editOrCreate$ | async }}</button>
        </div>
        <!-- POST/PUT Workspace button -->

    </form>

</section>

<!-- FIM - Parte de criar/editar/importar assunto(workspace) -->

<!-- INÍCIO - Corpo Tabela  -->
<section class="at-container table-container mb-5 mat-elevation-z2 card">

    <!-- header -->
    <div class="table-header-div">
        <h2 class="titles">
            Assuntos Existentes
        </h2>
        <!-- Busca -->
        <mat-form-field class="filter-header-select">
            <input matInput (keyup)="searchWorkspace($event.target.value)" placeholder="Qual assunto você deseja ver?">
            <span matSuffix><img src="../../../assets/images/search.png"></span>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- Busca -->
    </div>
    <!-- header -->

    <!-- table -->
    <mat-table class="table table-more at-default-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="workspace">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="at-intent-table-name-cell display-flex"> Nome
                Assunto
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace" class="at-intent-table-name display-flex"> {{workspace?.name}}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="createdAt">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Data de Criação </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace"> {{workspace?.createdAt | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="createdBy">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Usuário de Criação </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace">{{workspace?.createdBy ? workspace?.createdBy?.name : ''}}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedAt">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Data de Alteração </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace"> {{ workspace?.updatedAt | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedBy">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Usuário de Alteração </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace"> {{workspace?.updatedBy ? workspace?.updatedBy?.name : ''}}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="button">
            <mat-header-cell class="at-more-button-cell" *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workspace" class="at-more-button-cell">
                <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="at-more-button">
                    <i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="updateItem(workspace, 'Atualizar Assunto', formUpdate)">Atualizar
                        Assunto</button>
                 </mat-menu>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row, let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
    <!-- table -->

    <!-- img empty-data -->
    <div *ngIf="(!dataSource || !dataSource?.data || (dataSource.data?.length == 0))">
        <app-empty-data [subTitle]="'Adicione um assunto preenchendo os campos e depois clique em CRIAR ASSUNTO'"></app-empty-data>
    </div>
    <!-- img empty-data -->

    <!-- paginator -->
    <div [hidden]="!dataSource?.data || (dataSource.data.length == 0)">
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
    <!-- paginator -->
</section>
<!-- FIM - Corpo Tabela -->
```

file.ts method

```
public updateItem(workspace: Workspace, updateOption: string = '', formUpdate) {
        let description;
        formUpdate.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
        if (updateOption === 'Criar Versão Assunto') {
            description = `Criado a partir do workspace '${workspace.name}' em ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}`;
            updateOption = 'Criar Assunto';
        } else {
            description = workspace.description;
        }
        this.store.dispatch(new userActions.WorkspacesSelect(workspace._id));
        this.language$.next('pt-br');
        this.workspaceForm$.next(this.newForm(workspace.name, description, workspace.language));
        this.store.dispatch(new userActions.WorkspaceEditOrCreateState(updateOption));
    }
```

Both cases doesn't work.

I need a help to make it works like my attempt with a mat-button outside my table

Comment: Is  #formUpdate in same component as button callback?

Comment: Yes, formUpdate is in the same component, that is working in a simple mat-button, but in a mat-menu-item, it doesn't...

Comment: Can you create stack blitz to reproduce?

Comment: sorry man, that is impossible, there are a lot of dependencies that i'd have to install...

Comment: Can you at least post full template here?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: All code.html and method evoked edited

Comment: that is in second line, in tag section

Answer (score 0):

For me worked wrapping the function that uses the scrollIntoView() into a
setTimeout.

```
scrollTo(el: HTMLElement) {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }, 0);
}
```